# Avoid SizeChanged event on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a MainWindow Class which as a few Events - all of them should call a method in another class.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
    {          
        InitializeComponent();

        getdata.MainWindow = this; 
    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        getdata go = new getdata();
        go.clear();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        getdata go = new getdata();
        go.clear();
    }

private void comboBox2_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        getdata go = new getdata();
        go.clear();

    }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)         {
        getdata go = new getdata();
        go.clear();  //<-this causes exception on Startup 
    }

}
```

The Problem is that the MainWindow_SizeChanged Event is also triggered on Startup of the program but the clear method uses also some objects that are not yet created at Startup, which causes an error. How can I avoid this and only have this Event triggered when the size is actually changed while running the program?

Comment: Which objects are being used that have not yet been initialised?

Comment: Set a boolean flag when the objects have been created, and in the SizeChanged handler, do nothing unless the flag has been set.

Answer (score 2):

You have the IsLoaded property of Window.

You can check it before executing code.

Comment: By the time the resized event is called wouldn't the window have loaded?

Comment: When the window is loading and the SizeChanged event is fired, IsLoaded will be false so this would work

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an item is null when re-sizing so you can avoid this being an issue, this can be done using the [null coalescence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and [null conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) operators. If for example you are using the value of a textBox on startup but it has not been instantiated you can use this

```
string someText = tB1?.Text?
if(someText == null) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SizeChanged` Event gets triggered before the window is loaded. You can try subscribing to the `SizeChanged` event as part of `Loaded` event and unsubscribe it in the `Unloaded` as shown below.

```
//XAML
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" 
        Unloaded="MainWindow_OnUnloaded">

//Code Behind
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Size Changed Triggered");
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SizeChanged += Window_SizeChanged;
}

private void MainWindow_OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SizeChanged -= Window_SizeChanged;
}
```